# best way to make this array multidimensionnal

Tags: php

i have array like :

```
     $options = array (
    'af' => 'Afrikaans',
    'af_NA' => 'Afrikaans (Namibië)',
    'af_ZA' => 'Afrikaans (Suid-Afrika)',
     );
```

i want to add key for the country and for the id like :

```
 $options = array (

       [0]=> array ( 
                  'id' => 'af'
                  'name' => 'Afrikaans',
               ),

       [1]=> array ( 
                  'id' => 'af_NA'
                  'name' => 'Afrikaans (Namibie)',
               ),
```

)

Comment: "best way"? Ok tell me all the ways and I'll give you my opinion :)

Answer (score 1):

Make an empty array and then push new arrays onto it after you map your new values correctly.

```
$new = array();
foreach ($options as $key => $value) {
    array_push($new, array("id" => $key, "name" => $value));
}
$options = $new;
```

Comment: i like $new[] = ["id" => $key, "name" => $value]; if you are a high enough php version, which you should be by now probably.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a map with lambda:

```
$result = array_map(function ($id, $name) { return array('id' => $id,'name'  => $name); }, array_keys($options), $options);
var_dump($result);
```

Output:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
     array (size=2)
       'id' => string 'af' (length=2)
       'name' => string 'Afrikaans' (length=9)
  1 => 
      array (size=2)
        'id' => string 'af_NA' (length=5)
        'name' => string 'Afrikaans (Namibië)' (length=20)
   2 => 
      array (size=2)
        'id' => string 'af_ZA' (length=5)
        'name' => string 'Afrikaans (Suid-Afrika)' (length=23)
```